# Makefile - file detection using wildcard

Tags: makefile, wildcard

Here is my code to set the PATH_PROJET var correctly ->

```
PATH_PROJET = 0

-projet-build-path:
ifneq ($(wildcard $(PATH_CURR)/.path_root), )
    $(eval PATH_PROJET = .)
endif
ifneq ($(wildcard $(PATH_CURR)/../.path_root), )
    $(eval PATH_PROJET = ..)
endif

-projet-build-path-verif:
ifeq ($(PATH_PROJET),0)
    $(error Cant find $(PATH_PROJET)/.path_root)
endif
```

If i do an echo with the PATH_PROJET var i get the correct setup (. or .. depending) but when i try to use the same var in the second rule "-projet-build-path-verif" it use the first value of this var "0" but not the value that i just setup. This is the same problem if i use the var in a $(wildcard).

Someone have a solution for this ?

Comment: After some test i think its about how i set the PATH_PROJET var. I have try to write it in the begining of my Makefile like this:

    PATH_PROJET = ..

and then the second if work. so i think the $(wildcard) can use a var when you set it normally but not with the $(eval) command.

Is there any other way to set this var or to make it work ?

Comment: If it works now, then what are you asking?

Comment: it dont work now. just if i set the var mannually. i have edit my first post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly find another way to do it. I wasnt knowing that is possible to use if outside of a rule so i set the var with this way no (outside of all rule)

```
ifneq ($(wildcard $(PATH_CURR)/.path_root), )
    PATH_PROJET = .
else
ifneq ($(wildcard $(PATH_CURR)/../.path_root), )
    PATH_PROJET = ..
else
    PATH_PROJET = 0
endif
endif
```